# Add a dense vector to a sparse matrix in scipy (via broadcasting)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm wondering whether there is a way to simply add a dense vector to all the rows of a sparse matrix represented as a `csr_matrix`in `scipy.sparse` and returning a sparse matrix, ie trying to sum only the non zero element of the sparse matrix.

If I do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp
W = sp.csr_matrix(np.array([[0,0,1],[0,1,0]]))
v = np.array([2,3,4])
```

and then

```
sum = W + v
```

`sum` is obviously a dense matrix but with the zero numbers summed too. While, when I try to do:

```
b = (W != 0)
s = b.multiply(v)
sum = W + s
```

I obtain the correct result, but as a dense matrix. `b` is a sparse matrix, but `s` is not.

Comment: I obtain `b == True` and `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'multiply'`.

Comment: which version of python and scipy are you using? I'm using scipy 0.14, numpy 1.8.1 and python 3.4

Comment: SciPy 0.12 and NumPy 1.7.1. But I see that it works correctly with the latest versions from GitHub.

Comment: Do you mean it works as expected from the question, ie that it does not return a sparse matrix?

Comment: It works as you describe in the question.

Comment: It also seems that the problem is not that `+` of sparse and dense gives dense, but rather that `multiply` isn't smart enough to produce a sparse matrix, even though its return value is always *at least as sparse* as the left-hand side.

Comment: If `v` were to be sparse, `multiply` would be smart enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, the problem appears in `multiply`, which should produce a sparse matrix for sparse+dense inputs but doesn't. Convert to a sparse format to avoid that problem:

```
>>> s = (W != 0).multiply(sp.csr_matrix(v))
>>> W + s
<2x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```